# How to show download count of a product

Tags: 7, files, commerce

I am using drupal commerce for an e-commerce site. I have a view for listing the product. I want to show download count oof each product in product listing page as mentioned in the screenshot. How can I achieve this?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting up a view of product line items, adding both the product and order relationships, filtering by order state, turning on aggregation, grouping by Product ID and summing on the line item's quantity field.

Else try the https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_reports commerce reports module.